# Creating a column based on strings from two columns and another boolean column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a column based on some specific "rules".  I'd like to have a new column at the end "Result" with the following result based on the three first columns:

| is_return | From | To | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | Fir | Fem | FirFem |
| False | Tre | Syv | TreSyv |
| True | Syv | Tre | TreSyv_r |
| False | Tre | Syv | TreSyv2 |
| True | Syv | Tre | TreSyv_r2 |
| False | Snø | Van | SnøVan |

Basically if there's a trip that is not a return then just combine from and to, and add a number starting from 2 to it if there are multiple  (row 4). If it's tagged as a return trip then first check if it exists as a non-return trip, example given in row 2 and 3. But if it's tagged as a return without there being a non-return variant then keep this format as is (row 1).

Comment: No, If there isnt a non-return variant of it, even though it is tagged as a return then it should be treated as a example in row 2. :)

Comment: yes I got it reading it again, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need several steps (commented in the code):

```
import numpy as np

# compute the string for both directions
s1 = df['From']+df['To']
s2 = df['To']+df['From']

# compute the string is the correct order
# depending on the existence of the first trip
s = pd.Series(np.where(s2.isin(s1[~df['is_return']]), s2+'_r', s1),
              index=df.index)

# add number to duplicates
count = s.groupby(s).cumcount().add(1)
df['Result'] = s+np.where(count.gt(1), count.astype(str), '')
```

output:

```
   is_return From   To     Result
0       True  Fir  Fem     FirFem
1      False  Tre  Syv     TreSyv
2       True  Syv  Tre   TreSyv_r
3      False  Tre  Syv    TreSyv2
4       True  Syv  Tre  TreSyv_r2
5      False  Snø  Van     SnøVan
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect! One thing I noticed is if "to" and "from" are equal (which might happen sometimes) then they have a "_r" added even though is_return is false. But thats on me as I didnt include that case in the example. :)